# How to make a "Maze" with multiple paths and no dead ends?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion, maze

How would I go about programming a Braid maze in C# (Unity in particular) with multiple solutions?

A Braid maze from what I understand in my brief research is a type of recursive maze which allows loops, meaning no dead ends.

The closest answer I've found is in this thread dealing with how to create [more than one successful path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305644/how-to-generate-a-maze-with-more-than-one-success-full-path), but I can't figure out to combine the two as the examples used in the thread are for "Perfect" mazes.

By these steps you can get multiple successful paths from start to finish:

> 1. Subdivide the maze into three sets: Start (intially holding just the start cell), goal (initially holding just the goal cell), and undiscovered (all the rest).
> 2. Randomly remove walls between cells in the start or the goal set and cells in the undiscovered set, and move the newly discovered cell to the respective set.
> 3. Repeat until each cell is either in the start or the goal set.
> 4. Remove as many walls between the two regions as you want paths from the start to the goal.

I need is a step 5. that goes back and deletes all dead ends to turn it into a braid maze and I would be set! (Assuming that the maze size is n * n).

Answer (score 1):

How about the simplest approach: keep track of dead-ends as the maze is being constructed, and then after the maze is completed, for each dead-end remove one of its three walls so that it connects to some other part of the maze. It's possible that there may be some configuration of dead-ends for which this isn't possible to do without breaking the maze in some way, but I haven't been able to come up with such an example.

Comment: Any way you would be able to provide a code example of this?

Comment: @ryanhagz SE isn't a code writing service. Taking the information here and *literally any existing maze algorithm* you should be able to remove dead ends.