# Random obstacle generating algortihm in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, path-finding

My problem consists of finding a path from a given start to a given finish cell in a 2-dimensional array filled with obstacles (cells that I cannot access). While I think that I have found an algorithm that finds the optimal path each time given that the obstacle cells are known, the thing is that those obstacle cells are not specified beforehand and must be randomly generated each time I'm starting the program.

I'm stuck trying to find an algorithm that pseudo-randomly generates those obstacles while ensuring that each time a path from start to finish is indeed available. Anybody got any ideas? Thanks in advance.

This is what I've thought of so far for the obstacles (python):

```
free=N*N-4*(N-1)
obstacles=round(free*p)
#for j in (1, N):
obstacle_free_points = {S, F}
count=0
#j = j + 1
j=self.prims(N,S,F)
while count<obstacles:
    x=randrange(1,N-1)
    y=randrange(1,N-1)
    if (x,y) not in obstacle_free_points or j:
        self.grid[x][y]=1
        count=count+1
```

And this is my BFS for finding the path afterwards (python):

```
def bfs(self,N,S,F):
   previous=np.zeros((N, N),dtype=object)
   seen=set()
   q=Queue()
   q.put(S)
   while not q.empty():
       node=q.get()
       if node==F:
           path=[F]
           while node!=S:
               path.append(previous[node[0]][node[1]])
               node=previous[node[0]][node[1]]
           return path
       for n in grid.adjacent(self,node):
           if n not in seen:
               q.put(n)
               previous[n[0]][n[1]]=node
       seen.add(node)
```

Comment: When creating the obstacles, you could first (randomly) define a path and only put obstacles on (random) fields apart from this path. That way you would ensure that at least one path exists.

Comment: I think that if I do this, then the BFS that finds the optimal path will mostly end up with the path that I predetermined before creating the obstacles, won't it? When my path-searching algorithm starts, it's supposed to be an entirely new problem with given variables of obstacles, start cell and finish cell.

Comment: This entirely depends on the obstacle density. With few objects in the way it will be quite improbable that the optimal path is the same - the preliminary path will be superfluous then most of the time anyway. You could restrict your "randomness" so that there will exist a solution always but with a "blind" version like the one you implemented, there is no way around a test for the global criterion.

Comment: The obstacle density is not known or predetermined somehow. The purpose of the algorithm I am trying to create is filling the array with obstacles in a non-specified way, but even if the obstacle density ends up "randomly" being 90% of the array, still making sure that a path always exists.

Comment: Are the start and finish always on the edges?  That makes easier.

Comment: A maze generation algorithm might not be exactly what you want, but perhaps you can get some inspiration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: Related: [How to generate a maze with more than one successful path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22305644/1639625)

Comment: That does not seem to be a problem to my eye. Your programme can easily "forget" the existing path. And it is not said by any means that this path will be an optimal path. If the obstacle density is low, there will probably be shorter paths.

Comment: Maybe the solution is to modify your path-finding algorithm to gracefully handle the case of there not being a path from start to end. That simplifies your generation problem and also makes your code more robust.

Answer (score 0):

If the obstacle density is not predetermined, then this may work well for you:

1. Start with an obstacle in every square, except the start and end.
2. Randomly clear squares until the start square is connected to the end square.
3. Clear as many additional squares as you want.

You can use a disjoint set data structure to determine when the start and end become connected: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure.  Initially, each square is in its own set, and when you clear a square its set merges with the sets of all its clear neighbors.